# TL431A issue in voltage

Tags: opto-isolator

I am using TL431A for my design. Input side 4.7V below emitter and collector should be short and above 4.7V no output. But in my design it's the opposite. Can anyone suggest how to attain ex cat output.

I have attached my design below.

[image: Schematic]

Required:

4.7 < emitter n collector shd short
4.7 > no output

Comment: What you describe is impossible. To have CE shorted you'd need optocoupler LED ON but when input side is below 2V or so you will not have enough juice to light it.  whatever you modify the circuit

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd use of a TL431, which normally used as a voltage reference. In your circuit, the output phototransistor will be ON when the input (the righthand "A N"?) is greater than the TL431 reference, nominally 2.5V, assuming R145 is a sensible value. (Showing the values of the resistors would help greatly.) I suspect you need a rail-to-rail opamp as a comparator, plus a 4.7V reference (which could be a TL431).

Comment: Hi ,Res 148 + R154 = 10k

Res 158 + R159 = 11.21k

R149 = 10k

R145 = 120R

..

Comment: hi can you suggest me some circuit with my requirments